# fetch all post from wp multisite network and sort all the post in descending order on the basis of "Created by " term

Tags: theme-development, multisite, theme-customizer

fetch all post from wp multisite network and sort all the post in descending order on the basis of "Created by " term

```
$all_blog = get_last_updated();
     $countpost = 1;
     foreach ($all_blog as $key=>$current_blog) {
            if($current_blog['blog_id'] != 1){    
                 switch_to_blog($current_blog['blog_id']);
            global $post;
$custom_query_args = array(
  'post_type'  => 'post',
  'meta_key'   => 'xyz',
  'meta_value' => 'yes',
  );
```

here I am getting sorted array of different sub domain.. but still I want to sort this

Answer (score 0):

So you first want to order them by author and then by date for every author? 
You should use the `orderby` argument in your query, where you can pass an array.

```
$custom_query_args = array(
  'post_type'  => 'post',
  'meta_key'   => 'xyz',
  'meta_value' => 'yes',
  'orderby'    => array( 'author' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' )
  );
```

This should be something like what you want, otherwise look at the examples for the arguments in [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).